# Query to get the first and last row of records before a column value changes in mysql

Tags: mysql

Sample records(more accurate) in DB are like:

Id   DateTime               State  
1    2018-05-01 11:22:05    O  
1    2018-05-01 11:22:05    O  
1    2018-05-01 11:22:06    O  
1    2018-05-01 11:22:07    O  
1    2018-05-01 11:22:07    A  
1    2018-05-01 11:22:09    A  
1    2018-05-01 11:22:13    A  
1    2018-05-01 11:23:01    O  
1    2018-05-01 11:23:02    O  
1    2018-05-01 11:23:05    A  
1    2018-05-01 11:23:29    A  
1    2018-05-02 07:15:01    O  
1    2018-05-02 07:18:07    O

The output should be as like this.

```
1    2018-05-01 11:22:05    O
1    2018-05-01 11:22:07    O
1    2018-05-01 11:22:07    A
1    2018-05-01 11:22:13    A
1    2018-05-01 11:23:01    O
1    2018-05-01 11:23:02    O
1    2018-05-01 11:23:05    A
1    2018-05-01 11:23:29    A
1    2018-05-02 07:15:01    O
1    2018-05-02 07:18:07    O
```

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY. This is likely to prove seriously problematic in the not-too-distant future.

Comment: There's no primary key in the table.

Answer (score 0):

you could use an union

```
  select min(Datetime) datetime, state 
  from my_table  
  group by state 
  union 
  select max(Datetime), state 
  from my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try using a union here:

```
SELECT Id, State, MIN(Datetime) AS Datetime
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Id, State
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, State, MAX(Datetime)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Id, State
ORDER BY Id, State, Datetime;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: I've added few more records to my question. Pls check it again. Thanks!

Comment: Your query will group by ids and it's modes then for the each id's mode min and max date will be retrieved which is resulting differently. I've put more rows to have clarity. Pls chk it once aaain.

Comment: @CharanRaj See how TB provided a demo. Consider doing likewise, and updating your  question accordingly.